# SSRS Format date from YYYYMMDD to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

When I run the report, the date shows in format `YYYYMMDD` but I need to convert it to format `MM/DD/YYYY`

**For example:** `20150213` - expecting result `02/13/2015`

The expression below does not work. Suggestions?

```
=Format(Fields!InstallDate0.Value,"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Comes out where? in a prompt or on the report? How does it not work? Does it throw an error? if not what is the result?

Comment: When I run the SQL query, the results show "20150213" for example. Shows the same thing when I add it to SSRS. There are no errors. I need to convert that format to 02/13/2015.

Comment: @user3711442  Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 7):

It looks like `InstallDate0` is a string, not a date. Convert it to a date first, then format it:

```
=Format(CDate(Fields!InstallDate0.Value), "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: I receive #Error in all of the records for that column when using this expression.

Comment: Doesn't work without first converting the string to a date in SQL. The problem for many seeking a solution within SSRS is that they don't have access to the back-end data.

Answer (score 3):

Is the field stored in the database as a `DateTime` field, or as something else?

I'm going to assume that it's not a `DateTime` but an integer or string.

Assuming your column is called `InstallDate0`, change your query to use this expression (we're going to assume the source table has the alias `T1`):

```
InstallDate0 = CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(8), T1.InstallDate0), 112)
```

That will return your string (or int) as a DateTime.  You can now use the formatting capabilities of SSRS:

```
=Format(Fields!InstallDate0.Value,"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out, that you can define directly in the settings of your cell a user-defined setting like this:

```
MM'/'dd'/'yyy
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use:

```
=Format(Fields!InstallDate0.Value,"d")
```

If this doesn't work, my guess is that you are bringing the date into the report as a string. You can cast a `YYYYMMDD` formatted string as datetime in your sql query:

```
cast(InstallDate0 as datetime)
```

Comment: =Format(Fields!InstallDate0.Value,"d") --- All this did was put "d" in all of the records for that column. cast(IinstallDate0 as datetime) did not work in the query as well.

Comment: error I receive is "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Can you please provide your sql query?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me -

`Format(CDate(DateAdd(DateInterval.DayOfYear, 1, Now())), "MM/dd/yyyy")`

Requirement was to get current date + 1 in the format MM/dd/yyyy. You can replace `DateAdd(DateInterval.DayOfYear, 1, Now())` with your field value.

Comment: It is similar to the first answer. I don't have enough reputation to comment or up vote hence posting as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
=CDATE(MID(Fields!LAST_UPD.Value,5,2) + "/" + Right(Fields!LAST_UPD.Value,2) + "/" + Left (Fields!LAST_UPD.Value,4))
```

Not the prettiest solution, but fast and works fine.

Comment: This is the one!

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution that maybe can help someone, in my case, @ini_date is a parameter, so query conversion was not applicable....

When a date is in this format -> yyyymmdd, I 'constructed' a valid date string, with right() mid() and left(), concatenate it with slashes, and then convert it to date type, so it can be formatted.

Here's the expression>>

```
="Date: "&format(cdate((right(Parameters!ini_date.Value,2) &"/"&mid(Parameters!ini_date.Value,5,2)&"/"&left(Parameters!ini_date.Value,4))),"MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

just replace the "MMMM dd, yyyy" part, with whatever fits your report the most.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

Let's say InstallDate0 = 151116 (just replace InstallDate0 with whatever your field name is!)

I want to convert the following 151116 => 11/16/2015

**yyMMdd** of type string

to

**MM/dd/yyyy** of type date

The expression would be:
`=format(CDate(Mid(Fields!InstallDate0.Value,3,2)&"/"&Right(Fields!InstallDate0.Value,2)&"/"&Left(Fields!InstallDate0.Value+20000000,4)),"MM/dd/yyyy")`

if you wanted to do the same except from 20151116 => 11/16/2015

**yyyy**MMdd of type string

to

**MM/dd/yyyy** of type date

the expression would be the following:
`=format(CDate(Mid(Fields!InstallDate0.Value,5,2)&"/"&Right(Fields!InstallDate0.Value,2)&"/"&Left(Fields!InstallDate0.Value,4)),"MM/dd/yyyy")`

Tags: How to convert string to date with an expression for SQL Server Report Builder